# Laravel validator on a form and send post

Tags: laravel, forms, validation

I  used laravel validator. 
I have a form wih 2 fields
If i fill one field "NAME" and i leave the other "SURNAME" empty pressing SAVE button of the form appears required alert message on SURNAME but the name inserted in the NAME field became empty! And i think form send data anyway.why?I aspect that form doesn't send datas

Comment: Seems like something missing with name, Like error message span or code for getting old value of name inserted

Comment: Yeah infact now i resolved with old value tag in Blade view, but i dont understand why the framework dont stop form post if there are required alert messages

Comment: are you sure there is js validation? if backend validation form submits but redirects as soon as meet validations. And if backend validation used before form submits you needs to call that validation

Comment: if validation and form fields from blade file added it will be much easier to solve :)

Answer (score 0):

In the value attribute of each input you need to echo old("the-input-name") so it can retain the previous input before the error

```
<input name="name" value="{{old('name')}}" class="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `old('NAME')` to get the value of the field after the validation fails, blade example:

```html
<input type="text" value="{{ old('NAME')  }}" />
```

An example In case of update forms you should display the original value from the database unless there's an error:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ old('NAME') ?? $your_entry->value  }}" />
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#old-input) for more details